# Use AJAX to find element's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to find a way to use AJAX (Doesn't have to be AJAX if there is a better way please say so) in a Chrome Extension to download a few pages which the contents of each < a > tag are stored in array.

Every page has something similar - with varied inner text -:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#">Computer</a> <br />
<a href="#">Monitor</a> <br />
<a href="#">Mouse</a> <br />
<a href="#">Keyboard</a> <br />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to use/prefer jQuery.

Thanks, you don't have to code it for me. I'll figure it out myself if I get pointed in the right direction.

Edit:
I'm trying to retrieve data from other pages and store them in an array.

Comment: `$("a").text()`? I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I'm on page "home.html" I'd like to retrieve data from "things.html?pageid=x" and retrieve the text inside the a tags

Comment: I'm not sure how chrome extensions work, but if you can get around cross domain requests, then you could simply retrieve the AJAX data and parse it for the `a` tag text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myArr being the array you want to put them in...:

```
var myArr = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "myURL.html",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data){
        $(data).find("a").each(function(){
            myArr.push($(this).text());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) aside...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'things.html?pageid=x',
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(html){
        $(html).find('a').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

url - request the page @ things.html?pageid=x.

dataType - indicate the type of data the success function should parse for.

success - iterate over each instance of an `a` element found within the returned `html` document, then log the text value.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that pages are on the same domain, if you want to do multiple requests, then you probably want to check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when.